# Is a 3-form left invariant on SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$)?

Tags: lie-groups, differential-forms

This is from Spivak "Intro to Differential Geometry" Chapter 10 Exercise 26.

We are given G as SL(2,$\mathbb{R}$). P is the inclusion map from G to $\mathbb{R}^4$. $x,y,u,v$ are the coordinate functions $x^{11},x^{12},x^{21},x^{22}$, respectively, and dP is the matrix of 1-forms (dx$^{ij}$). In parts a) and b), I was able to show that $\mathfrak{g}$ is the set of all traceless matrices and was able to compute P$^{-1}$dP.

Part c) asks to show that the 3-form

v dx$\wedge$du$\wedge$dy - y dx$\wedge$du$\wedge$dv

is left invariant. 
I'm a bit confused on where to start. Should I do this directly? There's a proposition in the text that $\omega$ is left invariant if $\psi^*\omega$ is right invariant where $\psi$(A) = A$^{-1}$. Is that a better route?

Comment: Use the Iwasawa decomposition of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$; the result is trivial for each of the three components.

Comment: The text hasn't discussed decomposing the group like that. Is there a way to use the previous parts of the exercise to prove the claim?

Comment: You can go through the computation, but that decomposition makes it easier, and it's a useful thing to know generally. Why would its not being in the text be a problem?

Comment: It's not a problem. The text has been pretty good at motivating the exercises and having them build up to something. I was wondering if just wedging the 1-forms from P$^{-1}$dP was sufficient. Or if there's something more to prove.

Comment: You can, but the point of the decomposition is to reduce the problem to the subgroups $K = SO(2)$, the group $A$ of diagonal matrices, and the group $N$ of upper-triangular matrices. You still have to go through a bit of calcuation, but it's probably easier than writing an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In part (b) of the exercise you showed (or could have deduced) that $v\,dx-y\,du$, $v\,dy-y\,dv$, and $-u\,dx+x\,du$ give a basis for the left-invariant $1$-forms. What do you get when you wedge them together to get a left-invariant $3$-form? (Oh, I now read the comments and saw you'd already thought of this. Yes, it certainly suffices! Note that you already know that any two (nonzero) left-invariant $3$-forms must be constant multiples of one another.)